# Mockito test View visiblity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito

I want to write test for view visiblity.

I have something like this

```
@Test
fun showProgressBarTest() {

    val eventPlannerListFragment = Mockito.mock(EventPlannerListFragment::class.java)

    eventPlannerListFragment.showProgressBar(true)

    assertEquals(View.VISIBLE, eventPlannerListFragment.fragment_progress_bar.visibility)

}
```

But I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fs.wfm.ui.EventPlannerListFragmentTest.showProgressBarTest(EventPlannerListFragmentTest.kt:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
...
```

Is it possible to test it with Mockito ? Or I need use different test framework ?

Thanks for working example.

Comment: use espresso for testing ui

Comment: Don't do this. Use Espresso. Please never try to just create a mock fragment. It makes NO sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace isn't very helpful because your sample code doesn't include line numbers. But I can guess that the NPE happens at your assert statement. Mocks created by mockito "do nothing" by default. When you try to access your progress bar, it's null. Creating the mock fragment doesn't just magically create all the objects your normal fragment would have. Even if you called the fragment constructor, that would do you little good. The Android framework has to create these objects for them to be meaningful.